# Change pagesize in a repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

Is there a way of changing the pagesize of a repeater control depending on for example, the number of items belonging to a specific category?

I have written a count sql statement to count the number of items in a category and then have set that to be the pagesize but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
aQuery = "Select COUNT(Product.ProductID) From Product INNER JOIN Category WHERE Product.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID GROUP BY Category.CategoryID
```

this should give me a different value each time. But when I assign this value to the pagedData2.PageSize variable it doesn't change the number of items displayed on each page.

Is there a way of getting the number displayed on each page to change?

Comment: The repeater did not have page size, nether paging. Do you use some other custom paging ? The GridView have paging...

Comment: @Aristos I created paging in the repeater control.

Comment: Then if you are the one you going to create where did you stack ? The number of the displayed on each page is the number you have set - eg if you set 10 per page and you have 15 items, and you are on the first page then you have 10, if you are on last page you have 5 left (15%10).

Comment: In my paging function I have set the pagesize equal to the value that comes from the count in the sql query. I have the count happening on the page load so what I was thinking was that when the second page is called the page would reload and the new count would be generated and thus give me a new pagesize

Comment: Can you post the code of your custom repeater paging?